# How can I place a font awesome icon into the css content property if I'm using the font-awesome NPM package?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm, font-awesome

I'm using Fontawesome through their npm package, so that means I can't import it into css. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

from font awsome [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react) :

> Font Awesome now has an official React component that’s available for all who want to use our icons in their React projects.

If you are using React, you need the [react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) package or Web Fonts with CSS.